# To have a part of an 2D array then remove it

Tags: python

The code need to remove a hole part from a 2D array

what i need the code to do is

```
[["1", "fish"], ["2", "dog"], ["3", "cat"]]
```

Remove `"fish"`:

```
[["2", "dog"], ["3", "cat"]]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Are you hoping to have a function that can remove whichever entry has `"fish"` in it? Is there a reason you're not using a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)?

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [["1", "fish"], ["2", "dog"], ["3", "cat"]]
l = [i for i in l 
       if not i[1] == "fish"]
```

Comment: I did it wrong, could you try see it again to fix?